# convert hex to decimal value using python?

Tags: python

I want to convert hex to decimal value for the bellow given .txt file . specifically in  line number 1,  only for 73cb for that purposes I have developed python program . BUT it does not work and my output should be: 29643

> (10 (0 1 73cb 0))
> (13 (0 1 e7ba 0))
> (12 (0 1 0 0))
> (10 (2 1 73cb 1 3)(
> -0.05492209987825172 0.2133354572857093 0.2934898883481872
> -0.05491927490082463 0.211290383138306 0.2817208459424883
> -0.04367581308239386 0.212758053576771 0.287530716703097
> ))

```
with open("test.txt","r") as fi:
    id = []
    for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("(10"):
            id.append(ln[9:13])
            sd=print(id)
            dec=int(sd,16)
            print(dec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned the value of variable `sd` to `print()` which will return `None`.

What you need to do is to convert the `ln[9:13]` to int and then convert it from hexadecimal to decimal.

A code modified from yours is

```
with open("test.txt","r") as fi:
    id = []
    for ln_count, ln in enumerate(fi):
        if ln.startswith("(10") and ln_count == 0:
            sd=ln[9:13]
            id.append(sd)
            dec=int(sd,16)
            print(dec)
```

Additionally, I would recommend changing the variable name `id` to something else since `id` is the name of an inbuilt function in python. Using `id` as a variable name will cause function overriding.

Comment: @ veedata modified program gives two same output. i need single output for first line of the .txt file only. is any possible way to find out the output?

Comment: @Dev Updated my answer. Added enumerate() to server as a counter and updated if condition to only work for the 1st line of the file